# Infinitesimal multiplication

Tags: integration

Taking the exponential of the sum of logarithms gets you the product of the terms.

Now, if we have a function with positive values, we can form

$$\exp\int_a^b \ln f(t) dt.$$

In some sense, this is the limit of the product of the values of $f$.

Is there some result or theorem where this interpretation is used or gets more concrete?

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_integral